# How can i add multiple cases of one argument, make it a variable somewhere along the code and use that argument as one in function

Tags: function, csv

```
    import csv

    def Calc(process, shift, lc):
        f = open('C:\\Users\\keshabg\\Desktop\\sql_testing\\table_1.csv')
        csv_f = csv.reader(f)
        res_units = []
        res_hours = []
        sum_units = 0
        sum_hours = 0
        for row in csv_f:
            if row[2] == shift and row[3] == process and row[4] == lc:
                res_units.append(row[5])
                res_hours.append(row[6])
       for num in res_units:
           sum_units = float(sum_units) + float(num)
       for num in res_hours:
           sum_hours = float(sum_hours) + float(num)
       try:
           res_rate = round(sum_units/sum_hours, 2)
       except ZeroDivisionError:
           res_rate = "N/A"

       return "The Units Processed was: ", res_units , "The Hours worked was: " , res_hours , "The total units was: " , sum_units , "The total hours was: " , sum_hours , "The rate: " , res_rate
```

Hey Folks, my code is giving me the rate after the process, shift and learning curve level arguments are passed in the functions. There are 7 shifts and now what i want to do is, i want to make A through E day shift and F through G night shift making it a total of 9 shift but i dont have a clue how to do it. Any suggestions would be really helpful

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import csv

    def Calc(process, shift, lc):
        if shift == 'day':
            shift = ['A','B','C','D','E']
        if shift == 'night':
            shift = ['F','G']
        f = open('C:\\Users\\keshabg\\Desktop\\sql_testing\\table_1.csv')
        csv_f = csv.reader(f)
        res_units = []
        res_hours = []
        sum_units = 0
        sum_hours = 0
        for row in csv_f:
            if row[2] in shift and row[3] == process and row[4] == lc:
                res_units.append(row[5])
                res_hours.append(row[6])
        for num in res_units:
            sum_units = float(sum_units) + float(num)
        for num in res_hours:
            sum_hours = float(sum_hours) + float(num)
        try:
            res_rate = round(sum_units/sum_hours, 2)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            res_rate = "N/A"

        return "The Units Processed was: ", res_units , "The Hours worked was: " , res_hours , "The total units was: " , sum_units , "The total hours was: " , sum_hours , "The rate: " , res_rate
```